# Literature for cyclicity in Unruh effect

Tags: resource-recommendations, unruh-effect

On this Wikipedia page on [Unruh effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect), there's the equation $e^{2 \pi i H}=1$. Here, $H$ is the Lorentz boost hamiltonian.

I've read some literature on KMS states and Bisognano-Wichmann theorem, but none mentions this very equation, $e^{2 \pi i H}=1$.

Could someone please point me to a literature that explains this very equation, namely $e^{2 \pi i H}=1$? An Arxiv preprint, a book, a journal paper, anything that can be referenced properly.

An explanation of the derivation of this equation in this thread is also very welcome, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Not a reference, but if $G$ is the generator of rotations, the rotation operator by an angle $\phi$ is $\exp iG\phi$ (I think that the imaginary unit is just a covenience so the generator is hermitian). Upon euclidianization, boosts become rotations, so the Hamiltonian becomes a rotation generator. It's obvious that a $2\pi$ rotation is the identity, so
$$1=e^{i2\pi H}.$$

Not sure if this answers your doubt. This can be read in most books about Lie groups applied to physics. The rest of the Unruh temperature derivation can be found in Susskind's introduction to black holes.

Comment: Yes, this part is fairly trivial, since upon euclidization $t \to i \tau$ Lorentz transformation becomes rotation. The details that look unclear to me at this point are: A) how is Lorentz transformation a Hamiltonian in the case of boosts, and B) how does one come from $H$ to $H/a$ with $a$ being the acceleration. The proper reference to answers to these two questions would be appreciated, because the argument then becomes more exact and rigorous. Also, there are probably further references there too.

Comment: A) The Rindler hamiltonian is the generator of time translations, you'd have to prove that Rindler time translation is a Minkowski boost. You can more or less see this because in a space-time diagram constant Rindler time lines correspond to different speeds.

Comment: @anonymous B) It's because you have to multiply the hamiltonian by the radial coordinate, which is the inverse acceleration. Check the book I mentioned if you can.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot so far for help. I already checked Susskind's Introduction to black holes and strings, didn't find what I was looking for at a glance. I'll look at it some more. Any further information regarding references would be most welcome, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The Euclidean time $\tau = it$ is related to temperature by $\tau = \hbar/kT$ This parameter enters into Unruh-Hawking radiation because field modes are on either side, exterior region $I$ and interior region $II$, of the horizon. Those from the other side contribute to the field as
$$
\psi = \psi_I + exp(-\pi\omega/g)\psi_{II},
$$
for $g$ the acceleration. The temperature is $T = g/2\pi k$ and so $\beta = it/\hbar$. When employed in the rapidity equation this factor contributes an imaginary valued term, and is then cyclic. These have a $2\pi$ periodicity with $1 = e^{i2\pi H}$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for elucidating this point. Could you reference some literature on this particular subject please if possible?